# PHP/MySQL: update ordered rows by ordered select

Tags: php, mysql

I'm searching for an answer to my question for over an hour and am really desperate right now. I hope you guys on that aweseome website that helped me so often in the past will help me once again.

I need a solution in PHP/MySQL, no matter which does what. Performance is also not an issue. Sadly I have to work with given tables without primary keys.

The logic of the real world problem is, that one t2.name may have multiple events one can order by t2.date. A t1.name equal to t2.name might exist which may have multiple events one can order by another column t1.time. Now I want to merge the events for same names, matched by time. In other words: The row with t1.name with the latest t1.time should be matched with the same t2.name with the latest t2.date. The 2nd occurence of the name should be matched with the 2nd latest date and time and so on. How do I realize that?

Described in failed syntax - I already tried the following (and a lot more):

```
UPDATE table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.name = t2.name
SET t1.date = t2.date
```

and

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.date = (SELECT date FROM table2 t2
               WHERE t1.name = t2.name
               ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE t1.date <=> NULL ORDER BY t1.time
```

But both set t1.date to the latest t2.date, no matter which occurence of the name it is.

To give an example for the data:

```
t1.name t1.time
Pete    Nov13
Pete    Apr13
Pete    Jan12

t2.name t2.date
Pete    Mar13
Pete    Feb11
Pete    Dec13
```

What I want is:

```
t1.name t1.time t2.date
Pete    Nov13   Dec13
Pete    Apr13   Mar13
Pete    Jan12   Feb11
```

I hope I could make my point.

Thanks for any input in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create auto increment key for each table and match with the key

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.time, t2.date 
FROM (SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, t1.* FROM (SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY time) AS t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy) AS t1,
     (SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rowNumber, t2.* FROM (SELECT * FROM t2 ORDER BY date) AS t2 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy) AS t2
WHERE t1.rowNumber = t2.rowNumber
```